# VBA can't get numbers of rows from another sheets

Tags: excel, vba

can you help with with this problem?
I can get any value from another sheet in Excel with

```
Sheets(2).Range("A1").Value
```

But when I'm doing this:

```
Sheets(2).Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

I got an error

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object error

I tried all solutions from stack but nothing works... Why can I get any value from 2 sheet, but I can't get rows count?

Comment: Is `Sheets(2)` the `ActiveSheet` when you run this? If not you'll need to use something like `Sheets(2).Range("A1", Sheets(2).Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count`

Comment: O-M-G I was getting really nervous because I was fighting with this around 2~ hours, and didn't notice that I had no Sheets(2) before the second range, THANKS! write a normal reply to accept your post